# submit form from local html file

Tags: c++, html, linux, forms

I am programming a small c++ program in Linux, and I want to submit a form from a local HTML file, but I can't figure out how to do it.
I can't use wget or Qt because I have to give the destination URL, but I have to go throw the local HTML file because the information I want to send are relative to that local file dynamic content.
I thought I can modify the HTML file to add value ="value" in each input tag and add a line of Javascript to submit the form and then open the HTML file with the default browser using a Linux command, but I can't figure out how to save the resulting web page.
Can anyone help me?
I really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: You should think more in terms of HTTP requests and replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) `POST` request from your C code, you want some C HTTP client library. Then I suggest to use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

There are also C or C++ HTTP server libraries, such as [Onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion) and [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)

Or maybe you just want to make a [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) or [Fastcgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) program. (several libraries could help you).

<sub>(or perhaps I misunderstood your question)</sub>